# How does squaring these multiplicands permit inequality comparison to their multiple?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, square-numbers

This question pertains to Mosteller's classic book *Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability*. Specifically, this in regards to an algebraic operation Mosteller performs in the solution to the first question, entitled "The Sock Drawer."

Mosteller writes:

> Then we require the probability that both are red to be $\frac{1}{2}$, or $$\frac{r}{r+b}*\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}=\frac{1}{2}\text{.}$$
>   …
>
> Notice that $$\frac{r}{r+b}\gt\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}\text{, for $b > 0$.}$$ Therefore we can create the inequalities $$\left(\frac{r}{r+b}\right)^2 \gt \frac 12 \gt \left(\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}\right)^2$$

Despite much staring, and not knowing what to Google, I am stumped! In that last step, how does he do that‽

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>y$, then $x*x > xy$. But $xy = \frac12$ so $x^2 > \frac12$.

Similar for $\frac12 > y^2$.

Comment: my answer was directly derived from @Lord Shark the Unknown's answer, by the way. I just inserted one step that was omitted.

Answer (score 8):

You have two positive numbers, which I'll call $x$ and $y$, with
$xy=\frac12$ and $x>y$.
Then
$$x^2>xy>y^2$$
which is the same as
$$x^2>\frac12>y^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{r}{r+b} \color{blue}{\frac{r}{r+b}} > \frac{r}{r+b} \color{blue}{\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}}=\frac{1}{2} =\color{orange}{\frac{r}{r+b}} \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}>\color{orange}{\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}} \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

In a product of two (positive) things, if I replace one of them with something bigger, I get something bigger and if I replace one of them with some thing smaller I get something smaller.  So, if in 
$$\frac{r}{r+b} \cdot \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}=\frac{1}{2}$$
I replace $\frac{r}{r+b}$ with something smaller, say $\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}$, I get 
$$\frac{r-1}{r+b-1} \cdot \frac{r-1}{r+b-1} < \frac{r}{r+b} \cdot \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}=\frac{1}{2}  \text{,}$$ or
$$\left( \frac{r-1}{r+b-1} \right)^2 < \frac{1}{2}  \text{.}$$
Substituting the larger of the two for the second term gives the other inequality.